# c# drawing a rectangle on a picturebox?

Tags: c#

I have many images and coordinates of them with width and height. A picture is put in a picturebox and I send the coordinates to draw the rectangle on it. There are many pictureboxes on a panel.

I send their paths to a `PicturePanel` class also with some coordinates and width/height properties to draw a rectangle. However, my problem is that, it draws it, and immediately deletes it. If I don't put a messagebox after each image, i don't see the rectangles. Here is the code;

```
if (IsRun())
{
    MessageBox.Show("rontool true");

    Rectangle ee = drawARectangle(xCoor, yCoor, MainScreen.tempR.wid / ratioOfx, MainScreen.tempR.heig / ratioOfy); // I wrote this, it only creates and returns the rectangle.
    //MessageBox.Show("x : " + xCoor + " y: " + yCoor + " width : " + (MainScreen.tempR.wid / ratioOfx) + " height: " + (MainScreen.tempR.heig / ratioOfy));
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        pictureBox.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
       // e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
    }
}
```

This is in

```
private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e).
```

A for loop  is in another class, creates a picturebox, and initializes its x, y etc. however, it draws and immediately deletes it. or sometimes it doesn't even draw.

If I don't put a messagebox after each image, I don't even see the rectangles. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picturebox paint method is being called whenever Windows wants you to paint your picture box.  It looks like you only draw the rectangle some of the time.

```
if (IsRun())
```

Change your code to always do your drawing.

i.e. This code will not draw a rectangle. where Ben's example will.

```
private bool _once = true;

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_once)
            {
                Rectangle ee = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
                }
                _once = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but if all you want is to draw a rectangle, the following code will do it:

```
  Private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Rectangle ee = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);           
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
        }
  }
```

Comment: I call it in a for loop so the rectangles disappear.

Comment: You will need to show more code than you have done in your question. More specifically, what is happening in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

See code below.  I added a rectangle instead of a picture just to demonstrate the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 3;
        const int COLUMNS = 4;
        const int WIDTH = 10;
        const int HEIGHT = 20;
        const int SPACE = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Width = COLUMNS * (WIDTH + SPACE);
            panel.Height = ROWS * (HEIGHT + SPACE);
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
            for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)
            {
                for (int cols = 0; cols < COLUMNS; cols++)
                {
                    PictureBox newPictureBox = new PictureBox();
                    newPictureBox.Width = WIDTH;
                    newPictureBox.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newPictureBox.Top = rows * (HEIGHT + SPACE);
                    newPictureBox.Left = cols * (WIDTH + SPACE);
                    panel.Controls.Add(newPictureBox);
                    newPictureBox.Paint +=new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox_Paint);

                }
            }
        }
        private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            Rectangle ee = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);           
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
            }
        }
     }
}
```